# Why and When To Use uint8 instead of uint?

Tags: solidity, gas, opcode, optimization, state-variable

As far as I know `uint8` costs more gas than `uint256` (or `uint` they are same).

Let's say my variable can't be bigger than 100, and I already check for it with an `if` statement.

I saw many examples of `uint8` usage instead of `uint` and they say *"optimization"*. If `uint8` costs more gas than `uint256`, isn't it *"inefficient"* to make it `uint8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just have one `uint8` then yes, it will cost more gas than using a `uint256` because its data needs to be padded to fit a *word* which takes 256 bits. So it takes the same amount of storage but costs more because of the padding.

But the magic happens when you have more than one `uint8` declared next to each other. In that case they can be stored inside one *word* slot and therefore take less space. In theory you can therefore store `256 / 8 = 32` of these in one slot, but there is possibly some overhead and not that many fit - unsure.

When I said *declared next to each other* it means that they can't be packed if there is for example and `address` between them.

So using `uint` size smaller than `256` is useful only if you store more of those in the same slot - otherwise it just costs more than `uint256`.

You can read more about variable packing [here](https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/tight_variable_packing.html).

Comment: By "declared next to each other" do you mean to use inside the same struct or just declaring variables in lines next to each other is enough? I understand from the link you shared thay I need to declare them inside a struct. Thanks btw, this is the most logical explanation of why to use small byte variables.

Comment: I don't think they need to be inside a struct, but not 100% sure. And "next to each other" means that there is no other code between them.